# Retrieve last entry from one table based on query on another

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm having trouble retrieving latest records from one table based on a query on another table.  I've found many solutions which come close using the analogy of "last product ordered for each customer" but they are not perfect.

I have two tables with records linked using the field `dailyrecno_i`.  I would like to retrieve the last entry into table 2 linked to this key.

The tables and desired output are as follows, any advice appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your query so we can help you fix it.

Comment: Sounds like "groupwise max"; see the tag I added.

Answer (score 0):

This is from MS SQL but this should give you an idea. Note that i only replicated your desired output from your sample data so i'm not sure if there is any condition that i missed.

```
SELECT  [@table1].dailyrecno_i ,
    MAX([moc_noteno_i]) ,
    header ,
    MAX([text])
FROM    @table1
    LEFT JOIN @table2 ON [@table1].dailyrecno_i = [@table2].dailyrecno_i
GROUP BY [@table1].dailyrecno_i ,
    header;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer:

```
SELECT t1.dailyrecno_i, t2temp.moc_noteno_i, t1.header, t2temp.text from table1 t1 inner join (SELECT a.* 
FROM table2 a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT dailyrecno_i, MAX(moc_noteno_i) moc_noteno_i
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY dailyrecno_i 
) b ON a.dailyrecno_i = b.dailyrecno_i AND a.moc_noteno_i = b.moc_noteno_i) t2temp 
on t1.dailyrecno_i = t2temp.dailyrecno_i group by t2temp.dailyrecno_i;
```